# How compare Home folders and Active Directory with copy/remove folders?

Tags: powershell

i working on one project and i have problem. Assignment: The powershell script must compare Home user  folders on F:UserHome with AD by name. If name folder is same with name in ActiveDirectory, dont do anything and continue.

### But if user isn't in AD, script must compare:

1. If home adressar contains data, move this adresar from F: to Synology NAS(it is another server).
2. If home adressar is empty, it can be remove/delete.

But i must sort this home adresar to 2 folders(UserToMove.txt/UserToRemove.txt) for my boss too - with the same conditions.

If you don't understand something, I can explain it again. It's very important for me.

### Here is my script, which i create, but isn't working: - there's a mess in it

```
$homeDriveRoot = "F:\UserHome"
$leaversRoot = "\new storage on NAS"

$folders = Get-ChildItem $homeDriveRoot | Select -ExpandProperty Name


foreach($folder in $folders) {


$folder
#Compare by name
$u = Get-ADUser -identity $folder -Filter {Enabled -eq $true}|Select ExpandProperty Name

#If>0
if (($u).count -gt 0) {

   #If empty - remove
    if(($u) -eq $null){ Copy-Object -Path "$homeDriveRoot$_" -Destination C:\Users\branym.adm\desktop\remove.csv -Force}
   #If<0 write to file
   else{Copy-Object -Path "$homeDriveRoot$_" -Destination C:\Users\branym.adm\Desktop\active.csv -Force};


} 

#If dont search
else { echo "lost $u folder"}

}
```

Comment: How is the naming done for the users home directories? Same as AD SamAccountName?

Comment: Hi, yes. The user name home directories is same as AD SamAccountName...

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you:

```
$homeDriveRoot = "F:\UserHome"
$leaversRoot   = "\new storage on NAS"

# create two variables for the output text files. (they will end up on your desktop)
$removeFile = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath 'UserToReMove.txt'
$moveFile   = Join-Path -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) -ChildPath 'UserToMove.txt'

# check if the destination folder in $leaversRoot exists. If not create it first
if (!(Test-Path -Path $leaversRoot -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $leaversRoot -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}

# get a list of all folders in the $homeDriveRoot. 
# The items in the list are FolderInfo objects, not simply strings.
# If your PowerShell version is less than 3.0, write it like this:
# $folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $homeDriveRoot | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $homeDriveRoot -Directory
foreach($folder in $folders) {
    # see if we can find an AD user with this SamAccountName
    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $folder.BaseName
    if (!$user -or $user.Enabled -eq $false) {
        # there is no active AD user found for this folder name
        # test if the folder is empty or not
        # by using Select-Object -First 1 the enumeration of files and/or folders stops at the first item
        if ((Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -Force | Select-Object -First 1 | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0) {
            # the folder is empty, so it can be deleted
            # Add a line to the $removeFile
            Add-Content -Path $removeFile -Value $folder.BaseName
            Remove-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Force -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
        }
        else {
            # the folder has items in it, so move it to NAS
            # Add a line to the $moveFile
            Add-Content -Path $moveFile -Value $folder.BaseName
            Move-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Destination $leaversRoot -Force -WhatIf
        }
    }
}
```

Take off the `-WhatIf` switches from the `Remove-Item` and `Move-Item` cmdlets if the results are what you expect.
These switches are for testing and nothing actually gets moved or removed.

Comment: Super, THX. I will try it tomorrow or tonight. Can i type you, if i will have a problem tomorrow with that? And how i can move data from the one server to another server. How i can enroll way to another server in same domain? This script is started on CZPRGS024.macz but the server for (move)$leaversRoot is synology.macz/home. I don't know how to enroll.